# How to create a firebase cloud function to reset a users password

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions

I am working on an app, and part of the functionality of the app is having an admin login and be able to reset a user's password.

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("/removed-for-privacy.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://troop-30-elections-web-app.firebaseio.com"
});
    exports.resetPassword = functions.https.onCall((docId,newPass) => {
        console.log("step 2");
        admin.auth().updateUser(docId, {
            password: newPass,
        }).then(() => {
            const modal = document.querySelector('#modal-reset');
              M.Modal.getInstance(modal).close();
              resetForm.reset();
        });
    });
```

.

```
 resetForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
            console.log("Step 1");
            e.preventDefault();
            let newPass = resetForm['reset-password'].value;
            const resetPasswordFunction = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('resetPassword');
            resetPasswordFunction(docId,newPass);
            console.log("Step 1.5");
        });
```

I tried submitting the reset password form, but nothing happened. I looked in the console. There was no error, but I did see step 1 and step 1.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Functions code runs on backend servers and can't access the DOM of the web page that invokes it.  This means you can't do things like `document.querySelector`.  If the function requires information to run, you must pass that information from the client app as a parameter to the function.

Comment: I made an edit to my code, deployed my function, and tested it again. I added my new code to my post. I think your answer helped prevent an error that would have occurred in the future, but still nothing happens. I look in the console. No error, just step 1 and step 1.5.

Comment: If you have a new problem, you should post that separately and be clear about what you have now that doesn't work the way you expect, along with your debugging information.  Stack Overflow doesn't work well when the question keeps changing over time.

Comment: No, you have a different problem.  You did make changes based on my answer, but the problem at hand is completely different now.  What you have now is no longer about accessing the DOM in backend code.  Please revert question to what you had before (so that others can be helped in the future), and ask a new question.  Be sure to post your debugging details.